# Converting array into integer, but the integer is giving garbage value when more than 9 digits are added in it

Tags: java, arrays, integer

So I was doing a question on leetcode in which an integer was in an array form with its digit in left to right.

I wrote the following code to convert the input array into integer. But when 9999999999 i.e 10 9's or more are given as array. It is giving garbage value after adding 9th 9.
The code is given below. Please help me clear this doubt as I am just a beginner and I really cannot understand it. Sorry if its a silly doubt.

```java
public class YourClassNameHere{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number = 0;
        int[] num = {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9};
        for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
            number = number*10 + num[i];
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

I expected number = 9999999999

But I got number = 1410065407

Comment: Suggested area of research - what's the range of valid values for an `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, all values within a computer are stored in as *[binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)*, which are referred to as *[bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)*.

A *bit* holds a *0*, or a *1*.  And, a *[byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)* is, usually, 8 *bits*.

And, an *int* value, in Java, occupies *32 bits*—or *4 bytes*—of memory.

For example here is  *9*, in binary.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001
```

In order to store a negative value, computers utilize the empty space to the left.
So, here is a *−9* in binary.

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111
```

This means that the largest value an *int* can contain is *2,147,483,647*.

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

And, the lowest number, would be *−2,147,483,648*.

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Thus, you'll find that on iteration *10* of your *for-loop*, the maximum value is surpassed, and *"overloaded"*.

```
i =  0, number =          9,                             1001
i =  1, number =         99,                          1100011
i =  2, number =        999,                       1111100111
i =  3, number =       9999,                   10011100001111
i =  4, number =      99999,                11000011010011111
i =  5, number =     999999,             11110100001000111111
i =  6, number =    9999999,         100110001001011001111111
i =  7, number =   99999999,      101111101011110000011111111
i =  8, number =  999999999,   111011100110101100100111111111
i =  9, number = 1410065407,  1010100000010111110001111111111
i = 10, number = 1215752191,  1001000011101101110011111111111
1215752191
```

Here is the modified code, to produce the output.

```java
int number = 0;
int[] num = {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9};
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("i = %2d, ", i);
    number = number*10 + num[i];
    System.out.printf("number = %10d, ", number);
    System.out.printf("%32s%n", Integer.toBinaryString(number));
}
System.out.println(number);
```

Java, as with many other coding languages, offers a 64 bit integer value, a *[long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

This will contain the 11 digits you're looking for.
Simply, change *number* to a *long* data-type.

```java
long number = 0;
```

Output

```
i =  0, number =               9,                                     1001
i =  1, number =              99,                                  1100011
i =  2, number =             999,                               1111100111
i =  3, number =            9999,                           10011100001111
i =  4, number =           99999,                        11000011010011111
i =  5, number =          999999,                     11110100001000111111
i =  6, number =         9999999,                 100110001001011001111111
i =  7, number =        99999999,              101111101011110000011111111
i =  8, number =       999999999,           111011100110101100100111111111
i =  9, number =      9999999999,       1001010100000010111110001111111111
i = 10, number =     99999999999,    1011101001000011101101110011111111111
99999999999
```

As a final note, *Java* offers the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)*, and *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* classes, which will allow you to compute values without a constraint.

```java
BigInteger number = BigInteger.ZERO;
int[] num = {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9};
BigInteger numB;
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    numB = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(num[i]));
    number = number.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(numB);
}
System.out.println(number);
```

Output

```
999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value for `int` in java is `2147483647`

`9999999999` is much bigger therefore it's causing overflow and you're receiving 'weird' value

Every variable, not only in java, is technically just a list of bits and, due to the binary numbers definition, it's encoding some 'power of 2' value - depends on the length of a list. `int` consist of 32 bits and the first one is for 'plus/minus' and also we're counting them from `0` then max `int` value is (`2^30` + `2^29` + `2^28` + ... + `2^0`) = `2147483647` - all bits being set to `1`

You should use `long` instead here and respect it's range - you can exceed it too anyway

---

Read also:

- [Java data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [Binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)

Comment: It's worth to add that if there is need to have even bigger numbers than long can afford - there is always a possibility to use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` for floating point numbers